# I cannot convert a set of images taken from a FTP to a video using FFMPEG

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ftp

I am writting a python code where I am trying to convert a set of images that I take from a FTP into a video using FFMPEG but I cannot. I have tried, instead of reading the folder where the images are, to read a txt file with the name of the images that I want to use, with the format needed in order that FFMPEG could read it propertly, but I get always the same error: Protocol 'ftp' not on whitelist 'tcp'
In the same code, I also try to change the format of one video and change the resolution and size, and this part of code works well.
However, writting as input the same reference of the FTP, the images' code fail and the video's code works.
Besides, I have tried in my terminal as local the same command I write in the code for the images, and in local it works propertly, but not in the code.
Here there is a part of my code:

Video's code (it works):

```
command = """ffmpeg -i {i} -an -crf {r} {o}""".format(i=src_path,o=path,r=resolution)
```

An example of this command when I run this is the next (I dont want to write the exact ip and port):

```
ffmpeg -i ftp://user:user@ip:port/landing_ffmpeg/pruebas/pruebahd.mp4 -an -crf 45 tmp/pruebasalida456.mp4
```

And next the images' code (it doesnt work):

```
command = """ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate {ips} -i {i} -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p {o}""".format(i=src_path,o=path,ips=img_per_sec)
```

An example of this command is the next:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i ftp://user:user@ip:port/landing_ffmpeg/pruebas/prueba_imagenes/prueba06.jpg -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p tmp/videoimagen.mp4
```

And the error I get with this code is the next:

```
[ftp @ 0x560eb3e11800] Protocol 'ftp' not on whitelist 'tcp'!
[image2 @ 0x560eb3e09380] Could not open file : ftp://user:user@ip:port/landing_ffmpeg/pruebas/prueba_imagenes/prueba06.jpg
```

I dont get this error when I try to run the command of the video, only for the images. And both commands run propertly when I write in my terminal in local, with local paths.

I would appreciate if someone can help me to solve the problem and fix my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying it all. Try to whitelist the ftp:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist ftp -loop 1 -framerate 2 \
  -i ftp://user:user@ip:port/landing_ffmpeg/pruebas/prueba_imagenes/prueba06.jpg \
  -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p tmp/videoimagen.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have tried and I get the same error that before. I am still trying to solve and searching on the Internet different ways to solve it, although I have tried a lot of them that I have found on forums